# Convergence in probability related with sqrt

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

If $(x_{n}) \to x$ in probability convergence

Prove $(\sqrt{x_n}) \to \sqrt{x}$ in probability convergence

My attempt:

$$\text{Pr}(|\sqrt {x_n} - \sqrt{x}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \text{Pr}(|x_n- x| \geq \epsilon)$$

Is this true?

Comment: Not if $x_n, x < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Pr}(|\sqrt {x_n} - \sqrt{x}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \text{Pr}(\sqrt {|x_n -x|}\geq  \epsilon)=\text{Pr}(|x_n- x| \geq \epsilon^2)$$

Comment: what eq you reffer it ?

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai He is using that $\{ w \in \omega : \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} \geq \epsilon \} \subset \{ w \in \omega : \sqrt{x_n - x} \}$